# About solana web3 minting Token with phantom wallet

Tags: solana, solana-web3js, solana-program-library, solana-transaction-instruction, phantom-wallet

I wanna create a mint token by phantom wallet, here are the code snippet,

https://github.com/longmengua/contract-solana/blob/9231643fa85ff115404ad37f07453a3d47e160a1/solana/module/components/index/index.tsx#L88

Before minting a mint token, I need to get or create a token account, but somehow the creation of the transaction failed, could anyone help this?

https://github.com/longmengua/contract-solana/blob/9231643fa85ff115404ad37f07453a3d47e160a1/solana/util/getTokenAccount.ts#L5

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. Questions here must be self-contained, we're not going to go off-site to GitHub and dig through your code. Please [edit] a [mre] directly into your question.